# Android Device Chooser not show my device in one device

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working in Eclipse Luna in osX Yosemite and I have a little problem.
In one of my projects, when i try to execute the app The ADC appears blank without any physical device.
That project was working but when i changed the name of the project it stopped executing correctly.

After some investigate I've seen that in projects that I executed previously and have "Use same device for future launches" marked it works but when I need to choose I can't do it.

I've tried two different devices, change the USB cable, fix project properties,  reset the ADB server.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem.Adjust the bonds of Serial Name by making the area larger or smaller and your device will be visible.